# How to set resolution in remmina when connecting using command line?

Tags: command-line, display-resolution, remmina

Every time I connect RDP server in remmina using command line, the resolution is always set to 640x480 with dynamic resolution update turned off.

My command line looks like below:

```
remmina -c "rdp://Admin@server.domain"
```

I changed screen resolutions in Preferences -> Options -> Screen Resolutions leaving only 1920x1080, closed Remmina tray - still opens 640x480.

How to force it to open FullHD from command line and ideally also enable dynamic resolution update?

Answer (score 1):

Create a saved connection profile with the correct settings in the GUI, then launch the connection with

```
remmina -c /path/to/connection.remmina
```

The default save location for remmina `.profile` files is `$HOME/.local/share/remmina/` or `$HOME/.remmina/`.

If you're using the Flatpak version, the config files are in `$HOME/.var/app/org.remmina.Remmina/data/remmina/`

Comment: The problem is that I have dozens of RDP servers with credentials kept in KeePass, launched from KeePass and maintaining a profile for each RDP in remmina is not viable. Is there a method of just enforcing resolution and/or dynamic resolution update while just launching remmina from command line?

Comment: There is the `--set-option OPTION[=VALUE]` flag, but I don't know the option name for resolution. Have you tried another program? `rdesktop` was one I've used before. The only problem was that keyboard capture did not work on Wayland (Win key did not go through to the remote), so I switched to Remmina. Otherwise it worked perfectly.

Comment: Just an update - I am successfully using xfreerdp with the following KeePass command line:
cmd://xfreerdp -drive shared,$HOME/SharedRDP -cert tofu -size 1920x1080 -dynamic-resolution -v "{BASE:RMVSCM}" -u "{USERNAME}" -p "{PASSWORD}"